# Exactly what data is available in XBRL, and how far back does it go?

Tags: data, fundamentals, sec, edgar

What data is available from the SEC in XBRL format? Is it just 10-Qs and 10-Ks, or other filings as well?

When did XBRL become mandatory for all filers (or is it still not?)

Answer (score 1):

XBRL became mandatory for US filers on June 15th, 2011. The SEC requires XBRL data for:

- Quarterly and annual reports and transition reports
- Form 8-K revisions
- Limited Securities Act registration statements

XBRL instances for quarterly and annual reports would typically contain the usual items found on Income statements, Balance Sheets, and Cash Flows.